# How to display Admob on UIWebView Application?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4, uiwebview, admob

I have previously tried displaying Admobs ads on TabbarView based application. But when I try to implement the same on a UIWebView based application things don't seem to work right.

I tried to add the code inside `-(void)viewDidLoad` but the application crashed.

The methods i'm using inside my application include:

- `(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`
- `(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated`
- `(void) loading`

Where should I implement it to view in my application?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some code that shows us the code that you were putting in your viewDidAppear: along with what the crash error message was?

Answer (score 1):

You can add admob's banner view to window at the end of application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, after initialising viewController from XIB.

```
GADBannerView *bannerView;
bannerView = [[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)] autorelease];
bannerView.adUnitID = @"YOUR_ADMOB_ID";
bannerView.rootViewController = self.viewController; 
[self.window addSubview:bannerView];
[bannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

This way, admob banner will always be on top of the screen.