# How to open URL of AdMob in UIWebView in ios?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, admob

I am using AdMob in my app and I want to open ad in `UIWebView` in my app when clicking on AdMob View.

Comment: refer link http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1735838 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948475/how-to-display-admob-on-uiwebview-application

Answer (score 0):

No. We can't open the admob ads in UIWebView.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/ios/jYkFJ5xubcg